# Валидация IP адреса

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ip, asp.net-web-api

Как валидировать IP адреса для легального доступа? У меня есть следующий список:

```
185.71.76.0/27
185.71.77.0/27
77.75.153.0/25
77.75.156.11
77.75.156.35
77.75.154.128/25
2a02:5180::/32
```

Как видно тут есть разные маски и версии протокола. Доступ к некоторым методам API может осуществляться только с этих адресов, но я не знаю как мне узнать является ли текущий IP адресс легальным.

Я знаю, что есть класс `IPNetwork` из `Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides`, но я не знаю как мне сохранить список выше для валидации.

Comment: Валидировать сетевой доступ должен HTTP сервер или фаервол, а не ASP.NET сервер. Обращайтесь к сисадминам. И что значит "как сохранить"?

Comment: @aepot есть яндекс.касса. Некоторые её методы после оплаты могут обратиться к моему api методу. Обращаться они будут с определенных ip адресов (написаны в вопросе). Как мне узнать что ip адрес который стучится к методу является одним из описанных выше? Учитывая маску

Comment: Даете пул адресов админам, они просто настраивают фаервол/ALG так, что с посторонних адресов пакеты пролетать к вам в API тупо не смогут.

Comment: Мне не ко всему API надо, а к одному методу

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45712647/12888024 думаю отгадка где-то там. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/ip-safelist есть документация, похожая на то что вам надо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть удобная библиотека [IpAddressRange](https://github.com/jsakamoto/ipaddressrange), он же в [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IPAddressRange/)
Она умеет как в IpV4 так и в IpV6, включая маски и диапазоны.

И пример, как заблочить серые адреса. Можно по аналогии наполнить список своими адресами и настроить Middleware или любым другим удобным способом блокировку.

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Список частных "серых" адресов.
        /// </summary>
        private static readonly List<IPAddressRange> _privateIpAddresses =
            new List<IPAddressRange>()
            {
                IPAddressRange.Parse("0.0.0.0/8"),
                IPAddressRange.Parse("0.0.0.0/32"),
                IPAddressRange.Parse("10.0.0.0/8"),
                IPAddressRange.Parse("100.64.0.0/10"),
                IPAddressRange.Parse("127.0.0.0/8"),
                IPAddressRange.Parse("169.254.0.0/16"),
                IPAddressRange.Parse("172.16.0.0/12"),
                IPAddressRange.Parse("192.0.0.0/24"),
                IPAddressRange.Parse("192.0.0.0/29"),
                IPAddressRange.Parse("192.0.0.170/32"),
                IPAddressRange.Parse("192.0.0.171/32"),
                IPAddressRange.Parse("192.0.2.0/24"),
                IPAddressRange.Parse("192.168.0.0/16"),
                IPAddressRange.Parse("198.51.100.0/24"),
                IPAddressRange.Parse("198.18.0.0/15"),
                IPAddressRange.Parse("203.0.113.0/24"),
                IPAddressRange.Parse("255.255.255.255/32")
            };
        /// <summary>
        /// Проверяет, является ли IP адрес публичным
        /// (отсутствие в "сером" диапазоне адресов).
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ipString">IP адрес.</param>
        public static bool IsPublicIpAddress(string ipString)
        {
            var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ipString);

            return _privateIpAddresses.All(range => !range.Contains(ipAddress));
        }
```

А вообще, блокировки или белые списки по IP обычно делаются на уровне инфраструктуры - например в Nginx прокси.

P.s. [вариант в комментариях от @aepot тоже хорош](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/ip-safelist?view=aspnetcore-6.0)